# Transfer of data of a column from one SQLite database to another database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Can I transfer the data of a column of one database to the same column of another database?

Comment: Do you have 2 databases or 2 tables in the same db?

Comment: What do you mean with "transfer"? Creating new rows, or updating existing rows?

Comment: I mean the data which i have in column one want to fill in the other column of Other data data base

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ATTACH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command to attach one SQLite database to another. Then you can transfer values from a table in one to a table in the other. For clarity (and correctness if your tables have the same names), you should qualify your table names with the database name.

Make sure you `DETACH` the database afterwards.